# How do you get a circuit diagram from an output signal

Tags: circuit-design

I have to design a circuit diagram that would result in a LED giving off a specific signal (long, long, short, short, short, pause.)  That is MS in morse code.

I have one yellow LED, one 9V battery, one 40106 Schmitt-trigger inverter and as many wires, resistors, capacitors and diodes as needed.

How would I even start?

It is part of the class but the professor explains nothing.  The time of each wave is not set, as long as the first two are on longer than the last three.

Comment: Please draw the waveform timing for those of us not well versed in the required gaps between Morse code symbols.

Comment: Sounds like part of a class.  You start with the things you've learned in class.  Presumably, you were taught about oscillators (which you can build from an inverter and some capacitors and resistors) and flip-flops (which you can build from inverters.)

Comment: Even if the professor hasn't explained anything, you should have a book or a syllabus that tells you what things you should be working with.  What has your book got to say on the subject?

Comment: M is --. S is ... Dit (.) is one unit high. Dah (-) is 3 units high. One unit low between pulses inside a character. 3 units low between characters. 7 units low between words (doesn't apply here). So pattern would be 1110111000101010.

Comment: This reminds me of *code golf* where you attempt to code a problem with the fewest characters. These puzzles can be fun for some people, but they do not encourage good engineering practices. I can do this, but I would need more than 6 Schmitt inverters, and it is a hack. I am not impressed with this professor's teaching techniques.

Comment: @Mattman944 trust me no one in our class is impressed. We have had 4 classes with him and he gets annoyed when we make mistakes or take too long, he has no syllabus, gave us no supplementary reading and ignores people that ask too many questions… and he has tenure

Answer (score 0):

The circuit can be built from these building blocks. The NOR latch is built from 2 NOR gates, etc. Google NOR and NAND latch to see their behavior.

To get close to the requirement of 6 inverters will take some hacking. One asymmetric oscillator can create *dits*, 1010101010. Another can create *dahs*, 111011101110.

Now you need a circuit to switch between the two after 2 dahs. To do this with proper logic will take more inverters than you are allowed. You will need to hack it to switch after a long time delay. The timing will need to be precise (poor design practice for this type of circuit).

You probably want to use oscillators that start low, or else the first pulse will be longer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fz4TCw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>